# How to facilitate theme customisations in Wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I've created a Wordpress Theme that I decided to do a bit of extra development on so that it can be packaged up and deployed as a theme for anybody who wants to download and use it

As is pretty standard for Wordpress Themes, I've added an options page, where the user can customise the theme, i.e. change background colours, font-sizes, etc.

Currently I'm facilitating these theme customisations by embedding the new style i.e. `<?php print "background-color: {$options['user_selected_bg_color']"}; ?>` in the page (style tag in head)

The only other way I can think of doing this is by perhaps adding a secondary stylesheet below the primary one that is actually PHP with the header mime-type change.

What other ways are there to do this? Is there an "accepted" method for facilitating the users theme customisations amongst Wordpress Theme Developers?

Comment: A third option would be to write out an asset file and save it over the previous. How you downloaded other WordPress theme packages to study how it's done by the developers?

Comment: If you're going to limit the options (as in theme blocks like `winter` and `'57 Chevy`) instead of allow abstract customizations like `color: #dac3d9`, you can set up flags like I demonstrate with [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/ApSk3/), and then detect and add those flags to the `html` or `body` tag/element. Take a look at [jQuery UI ThemeRoller's HTML tag](http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/) using `Inspect Element` (and not View Source) to see a complex example of this in action. I think Bootstrap also utilizes this technique, as well.